# Erc20 token and buying

Tags: erc20

with my own 0x363.. wallet address
I am generating erc20 token and when I issue this erc20 contract a contract address is generated (0x966D...). that is, I have one wallet address and one coin address.

E.g:
1 mytoken = 1 ethereum

E.g:
If a user buys my token with metamask, the user will pay ethereum.
And where is 1 ethereum. Why is this ethereum not uploaded to my admin account (0x363..). this ethereum goes to erc20 (0x966D ..) as far as I understand. How can I get this ethereum to my admin account?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming; the [stackexchange devoted specifically to Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) would be a much better place to ask about things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How can I get this ethereum to my admin account?*

Based on the context of the question (the ETH is paid to the **token** contract - not to a **DEX pair** contract), I'm assuming you have a custom buy function.

You can expand this buy function to use the `transfer()` method of `address payable` to transfer the just received ETH to your admin address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyToken {
    address admin = address(0x123);

    function buy() external payable {
        // transfers the whole ETH `value` sent to the `buy()` function
        // to the `admin` address
        payable(admin).transfer(msg.value);

        // ... rest of your code
    }
}
```

Contract bytecode is immutable (with some edge case exceptions), so in order to perform the change, you'll need to deploy a new contract - can't expand the already deployed contract.